# Why ldap_modify is not sending the item value to ldap server?

Tags: php, ldap

I wrote a piece of software using PHP that resets the password of the user. It works pretty well in my old Apache Server running version 5.1.4 of PHP (and I am not sure but I believe that it has openldap version 2.2.13.6). Now I am porting the same software to a newer version of Apache (actually Weblogic 10.3.6).

In this new environment I have installed PHP 5.3.27 and openldap 2.4.30 (according to phpinfo).

The fragment of code that does the change of password is this one:

```
$modifyPass["userPassword"]=$pass;
if (ldap_mod_replace($ds,$dn,$modifyPass)) 
{print "success";}
else {print "Fail";}
```

I ran a network sniffer while running the code in both versions of PHP and in both cases you can see the modifyrequest in wiershark, and a succefull modifyresponse from the ldap server, but the modifyrequest of the newer PHP version has an empty value for the userPassword attribute. (The old version works perfectly and it shows the expected value for the item).

I tried with ldap_modify and ldap_mod_replace. I had the same result.

Any help, would be inmensely appreciated,
thank you very much,
Andres

PS: I should clarify that the code always choses the branch of "print success", and also I made sure that $pass has the right value.

Comment: Try the [password modify extended operation](http://ldapmaven.com/2011/11/12/ldap-password-modify-extended-request/) to see if it behaves any differently.

Comment: Ok, I can't answer my own question, because I could not find WHY ldap_modify is not sending the value. BUT, I decided to use Apache instead of WebLogic web server (BEA?). This time I installed php 5.5.4 and apache 2.4. This time it works flawlessly. I did not touch my software just php/apache.